# Java String Regex replacement

Tags: java, regex, string

Sample Input:

```
a:b
a.in:b
asds.sdsd:b
a:b___a.sds:bc___ab:bd
```

Sample Output:

```
a:replaced
a.in:replaced
asds.sdsd:replaced
a:replaced___a.sds:replaced___ab:replaced
```

String which comes after `:` should be replaced with custom function.
I have done the same without `Regex`. I feel it can be replaced with regex as we are trying to extract string out of specific pattern.

For first three cases, it's simple enough to extract `String` after `:`, but I couldn't find a way to deal with third case, unless I split the string `___` and apply the approach for first type of pattern and again concatenate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace only the letters with exists next to `:` with the string `replaced`.

```
string.replaceAll("(?<=:)[A-Za-z]+", "replaced");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tU3aV3/1)

or

If you also want to deal with digits, then add `\d` inside the char class.

```
string.replaceAll("(?<=:)[A-Za-z\\d]+", "replaced");
```

Comment: just to update, `:bc___` can be something like this `:b566` or `:4545`. I guess we should consider numbers too

Comment: then add `\\d` inside the char class.

Comment: sorry for not clarifying. It can contain any data `:b@g.com`  or `:b@_g+.com` .But guranteed not to contain `:` and `____` as these are self-defined pattern

Comment: could be dump question now, how do I call custom function instead of directly replacing with "replaced". My custom function should get the matching string `matcher.group()`

Comment: ask this as a new question. I think you need to include the replaceAll function within `while` function.

Answer (score 4):

```
(:)[a-zA-Z]+
```

You can simply do this with `string.replaceAll`.Replace by `$1replaced`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/18